# Empty spaces at the end of row Recyclerview with GridLayoutManger

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using `recyclerview` with `gridlayoutmanger` with `spancount` 2 containing fixed 12 elements only in `recyclerview`.On tablets in landscape mode the empty space is remaining after the sixth element. I want to fill the empty space with the elements from second row. If space is there than then first row contain either 6, 7, 8 ,9 ... elements depends upon the remaining space.

Comment: Try to use horizontal mode, and set count of items programmatically

Comment: I already using orientation horizontal.

Comment: That's the correct behaviour for horizontal mode grid layout.

Try using vertical mode, and use differing span count for each screen types, (although it will cause the layout to have more than 2 rows).

Answer (score 0):

Use FlexLayoutManger with recycler view :

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) context.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.COLUMN);
layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_END);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

See this link
https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview