# What layouts should I use in terms of performance?

Tags: android, mobile, layout

I'm developing an android app that uses a `RecyclerView` to display lot of items, so I want the layout of those items to be **as fast as possible** and **as flat as possible**.

The final layout of the recycler view's items should look something like this:

[image]

Where the green Items should equally spread across the bottom. 
Whats the best way to do this?

I have few options:

- using `LinearLayouts`
- using `RelativeLayouts`
- using `ConstraintLayouts`
- using some kind of combination of the layouts

However, I think I cannot avoid some nesting of layouts here? Can someone give me a brief overview what's best practice to structure this layout?

I have tried something like

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <Item />
    <Item />
    <ConstraintLayout> // For Stretching
        <LinearLayout>
          <SubItem />
          <SubItem />
        </LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout>
          <SubItem />
          <SubItem />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
          <SubItem />
          <SubItem />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ConstraintLayout>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

But I think it can be done with less nesting?
There is no scrolling required, but the views should wrap their content vertically.

Comment: Does this view can scroll vertically and green views horizontally

Comment: No, no scrolling requiered, but it has to set its size vertically depending on its content (wrap_content)

Comment: See this link, May it help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49690257/empty-spaces-at-the-end-of-row-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanger/49690628#49690628

Comment: Are there blue items to consider or are we just talking about the green and the orange items?